# Getting the IP Address Of A client For a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, ip

I am using JAX-WS and I am having trouble retrieving the client information that is consuming a webservice. I've found out how to do it with JAX-RPC, and Apache Tomcat Axis, but not with JAX-WS. Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

What about this:

```
@WebService
public class MyService {

  @Resource
  WebServiceContext wsContext; 

  /**
   * Web service operation
   */ 
  @WebMethod 
  public String myMethod() { 

    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
    System.out.println("Client IP = " + req.getRemoteAddr()); 

  }

}
```

Comment: I think I just missed the @Resource annotation.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is the best description of how to do this on the whole wide web. ;) Thank you, Pascal!

Comment: I try same  but mc size 22 and  "request" is null. I can't understand why, have you any idea?

Comment: This works only in a servlet container but the OP asked for a JAX-WS implementation. Take a look at [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727989/jax-ws-getting-client-ip) for a good summary to retrieve the IP address in different environments.

Answer (score 5):

Or this:

```
@Path("terminal")
public class terminal {
    @Context private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest hsr;
    @GET
    @Path("get_ip")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String get_ip()
    {
            return ip = hsr.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not applicable to REST only?

Answer (score 3):

Taking a huge and appreciated hint from Zayin and Darren's answer/edit, I tried this, and it works too.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("ip")
public String sayIP(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("p1") String p1, ...) {
    return req.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getIp(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    return req.getRemoteHost();
}
```

Comment: @Context cannot be identified, and no import is suggested, what is this exactly ?

Comment: @united-expression, https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html, https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html