# wsContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST) returns null on Jetty?

Tags: java, soap, jetty, jax-ws

I have an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641594/geting-the-ip-address-of-a-client-for-a-webservice). I have that exact code running on a **Jetty Server**, and other **SOAP** web services work perfectly. However, on this  line:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
System.out.println("Client IP = " + req.getRemoteAddr());
```

The server crashes with a null pointer exception. `mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)` is returning null.

By comparison, `mc.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD`) returns "POST", so I assume that's working.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133436/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-httpservletrequest-object-when-using-java-web-servic) fix to no avail.

I've also tried using the @Context annotation instead and got the same issue.

A System.out.println(mc) yields this:

```
{javax.xml.ws.wsdl.port={http://my.test.namespace.com/}testWSDLPort,
 javax.xml.ws.soap.http.soapaction.uri="", 
 com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.OneWayOperation=null, 
 javax.xml.ws.http.request.pathinfo=null, 
 ...
 ...
```

and so on, and the list of values does NOT include javax.xml.ws.servlet.request, which is the value of MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST. What do I need to do to make sure the MessageContext has this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Jetty HTTP SPI JAX-WS implementation doesn't appear to properly inject the MessageContext into a web service. Try switching to Apache CXF instead. Once you have

1. cxf-2.6.2.jar
2. neethi-3.0.2.jar
3. xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar

on your project build path, you have to create a servlet class that extends the CXFNonSpringServlet and overrides the loadBus function like so:

```
public class SOAPServlet extends CXFNonSpringServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Object> endpoints;


    public SOAPServlet(){
        endpoints = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadBus(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
        super.loadBus(servletConfig);        

        // You could add the endpoint publish codes here
        Bus bus = getBus();
        BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
        Set s = endpoints.entrySet();
        Iterator p = s.iterator();
        while(p.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)p.next();
            String address = (String)m.getKey();
            Object impl = (Object)m.getValue();
            System.out.println("Publishing " + address);
            Endpoint.publish(address, impl);
        }
    }
    public void publish(String address, Object impl){
        endpoints.put(address, impl);
    }
}
```

And then where you are configuring your server, add these lines:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    // Configure SOAP servlet
    SOAPServlet servlet = new SOAPServlet();
    ServletHolder SOAPServletHolder = new ServletHolder(servlet);

    ServletContextHandler SOAPContext = new ServletContextHandler(server,"/",ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    SOAPContext.addServlet(SOAPServletHolder, "/*");

    // Set server context handlers
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler []{SOAPContext});
    server.setHandler(contexts);

    // Publish SOAP Web service endpoints
    servlet.publish("/MyWebServiceRelativeURL", new MyWebServiceImpl());

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue - instead of retrieving the SERVLET_REQUEST like that and getting null, I used the following:

```
com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange server = (com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange)     mc.get("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.http.exchange");
System.out.println("Client IP = " + server.getRemoteAddress().toString());
```

This allows for retrieving of the IP address, port, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to this code anymore or I would test, hopefully this helps someone though.