# How do I get the full request url in a Java jax-ws @WebService @WebMethod?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

The client calls a web service at *http://localhost:8080/soap/v1/myservice*

This maps nicely to my service class, and my method gets called.

In some situations I'd like to have access within that method to information from the http request. What I just can't get is the path (or the full url).

There is information available in the injectable WebServiceContext, like so:

```
@WebService @Service
public class MySoapService {

  @Resource
  private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

  @WebMethod
  public String requestInfo() {
    MessageContext mc = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
    return makeMsg(mc);
  }

  private String makeMsg(MessageContext messageContext) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Request method: "+messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD));
    sb.append(", Path: "+messageContext.get(MessageContext.PATH_INFO));
    sb.append(", Query string: "+messageContext.get(MessageContext.QUERY_STRING));
    sb.append(", User agent: "+((Map)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).get("user-agent"));
    sb.append(", Content type: "+((Map)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).get("content-type"));
    sb.append(", Http accept: "+((Map)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).get("accept"));
    sb.append(", Http host: "+((Map)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).get("host"));
    sb.append(", Connection: "+((Map)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)).get("connection"));
    System.out.println(messageContext);
    return sb.toString();
  }

}
```

However, the path requested by messageContext.get(MessageContext.PATH_INFO)) is null.

Example result:

> Request method: POST, Path: null, Query string: null, User agent: [JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01], Content type: [text/xml; charset=utf-8], Http accept: [text/xml, multipart/related], Http host: [localhost], Connection: [keep-alive]

I am also able to get the info whether it was https or not, but it requires an ugly cast and field access:

```
((AbstractWebServiceContext) webServiceContext).getRequestPacket().wasTransportSecure
```

In the debugger I can see the url's path, but without reflection I can't get to it. There just has to be a clean way to get it, no?

[image: intellij debugger shows url]

Since SO resized my screenshot without adding a click-to-enlarge, here is the important part: [image]

My dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

which itself uses

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are some similar questions on SO, but none helps me.

`mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)` returns `null` as for this person [wsContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST) returns null on Jetty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519496/wscontext-getmessagecontext-getmessagecontext-servlet-request-returns-null-o) or this [Geting the IP Address Of A client For a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641594/geting-the-ip-address-of-a-client-for-a-webservice) or this [How can I access the ServletContext from within a JAX-WS web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261348/how-can-i-access-the-servletcontext-from-within-a-jax-ws-web-service)

To reproduce, this code is available on GitHub https://github.com/optimaize/soapworks at first run (debug) the Boot class, then the RequestInfoServiceImplTest.

Answer (score 3):

Please check 
`WebServiceContext.getMessageContext().get( "org.apache.cxf.request.url" ).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to extract the URI using reflection. I'm using it as a temporary hack.

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WebServiceContextDelegate;
import com.sun.xml.ws.server.AbstractWebServiceContext;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 */
public class RequestUrlExtractor {

    /**
     * Best effort. Uses reflection.
     * See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234303/how-do-i-get-the-full-request-url-in-a-java-jax-ws-webservice-webmethod
     * @return starting with a slash, eg "/my/service/url"
     * @throws RuntimeException in case of failure (api change)
     */
    @NotNull
    public String extractUri(@NotNull WebServiceContext webServiceContext) {
        WebServiceContextDelegate webServiceContextDelegate = ((AbstractWebServiceContext) webServiceContext).getRequestPacket().webServiceContextDelegate;
        Class<?> c = webServiceContextDelegate.getClass();
        Field field;
        try {
            field = c.getDeclaredField("request");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object result;
        try {
            result = field.get(webServiceContextDelegate);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        c = result.getClass();
        try {
            field = c.getDeclaredField("request");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object request;
        try {
            request = field.get(result);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        java.lang.reflect.Method method;
        try {
            method = request.getClass().getMethod("getRequestURI");
        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Object uri;
        try {
            uri = method.invoke(request);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (!(uri instanceof String)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not a string!");
        }
        return (String)uri;
    }

}
```